# AndroidView with TopAppBar -> content is hidden behind TopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I am using `AndroidView` combined with a `Scaffold` with `TopAppBar` and I am seeing the behavior that the content of the `AndroidView` as also behind the `TopAppBar` and I do not want it because it hides content at the top.

This is what I mean:

[image]

You can see that the `ConstraintLayout` is behind the `TopAppBar`. Is there anything I can do to prevent that? My content at the top is hidden. This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RecyclverTestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Scaffold(topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(title = {
                            Text(
                                text = "sadsd",
                            )
                        })
                    }) {
                        GreetingX()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingX() {
    AndroidView(factory = { context ->
        val cl = ConstraintLayout(context)

        cl.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        cl.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark))

        cl
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was ignoring the `PaddingValues` I had to use which the lambda provides